# How to merge/join/append two spatial overlapping datasets (From/To)?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, append

I have two datasets that have an ID that overlaps.  To make this shorter, I'm only going to post the ID that has an overlap.  For the From/To interval that overlaps, I want to choose the second dataset, df2, except with Python I don't know how to do it.  I know its probably easier/easiest with SQL but I want to know if it is possible with Python.  There are extra variables in df2 that I want to come along for the ride but for the variables that are the same, I want to choose df2 instead of df1 for the From/To overlap between the two.

df1

| ID | From | To | Q | RM | RQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MRC-17 | 447 | 472 | 0.63 | 42 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 472 | 502 | 2.5 | 42 | 20 |
| MRC-17 | 502 | 503.8 | 2.5 | 37 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 503.8 | 509.7 | 0.42 | 29 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 509.7 | 527 | 0.38 | 32 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 527 | 545 | 0.38 | 32 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 545 | 551 | 3.33 | 47 | 26.67 |
| MRC-17 | 551 | 576 | 0.38 | 32 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 576 | 579.5 | 6.07 | 47 | 48.57 |
| MRC-17 | 579.5 | 597 | 0.38 | 32 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 597 | 616 | 0.38 | 32 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 616 | 626 | 4.75 | 47 | 38 |
| MRC-17 | 626 | 647 | 0.38 | 32 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 647 | 662 | 0.83 | 34 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 662 | 677 | 0.38 | 37 | 10 |

df2

| ID | From | To | H | DP | DR | IV | No | RQ | RM | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MRC-17 | 499 | 504 | 1 | U | S | D | 7 | 50 | 32 | 2.08 |
| MRC-17 | 504 | 510 | 2 | P | R | D | 7 | 25 | 32 | 0.78 |
| MRC-17 | 510 | 545 | 0 | P | K | F | 9 | 5 | 18 | 0.02 |
| MRC-17 | 545 | 565 | 0 | P | K | F | 8 | 60 | 28 | 0.33 |
| MRC-17 | 565 | 575 | 0 | P | K | F | 9 | 5 | 18 | 0.02 |
| MRC-17 | 575 | 581 | 1 | P | K | F | 7 | 70 | 34 | 0.49 |
| MRC-17 | 581 | 600 | 0 | P | K | F | 8 | 20 | 23 | 0.11 |
| MRC-17 | 600 | 612 | 0 | P | K | F | 9 | 5 | 18 | 0.02 |
| MRC-17 | 612 | 634 | 1 | P | S | C | 7 | 70 | 38 | 2.92 |
| MRC-17 | 634 | 647 | 0 | P | S | F | 9 | 5 | 22 | 0.04 |
| MRC-17 | 647 | 662 | 2 | P | S | B | 7 | 55 | 39 | 4.58 |
| MRC-17 | 662 | 677 | 0 | P | S | F | 9 | 15 | 22 | 0.13 |

Resulting in Final (-99 means missing for numeric, X for char):

| ID | From | To | H | DP | DR | IV | No | RQ | RM | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MRC-17 | 447 | 472 | -99 | X | X | X | -99 | 10 | 42 | 0.63 |
| MRC-17 | 472 | 499 | -99 | X | X | X | -99 | 20 | 42 | 2.50 |
| MRC-17 | 499 | 504 | 1 | U | S | D | 7 | 50 | 32 | 2.08 |
| MRC-17 | 504 | 510 | 2 | P | R | D | 7 | 25 | 32 | 0.78 |
| MRC-17 | 510 | 545 | 0 | P | K | F | 9 | 5 | 18 | 0.02 |
| MRC-17 | 545 | 565 | 0 | P | K | F | 8 | 60 | 28 | 0.33 |
| MRC-17 | 565 | 575 | 0 | P | K | F | 9 | 5 | 18 | 0.02 |
| MRC-17 | 575 | 581 | 1 | P | K | F | 7 | 70 | 34 | 0.49 |
| MRC-17 | 581 | 600 | 0 | P | K | F | 8 | 20 | 23 | 0.11 |
| MRC-17 | 600 | 612 | 0 | P | K | F | 9 | 5 | 18 | 0.02 |
| MRC-17 | 612 | 634 | 1 | P | S | C | 7 | 70 | 38 | 2.92 |
| MRC-17 | 634 | 647 | 0 | P | S | F | 9 | 5 | 22 | 0.04 |
| MRC-17 | 647 | 662 | 2 | P | S | B | 7 | 55 | 39 | 4.58 |
| MRC-17 | 662 | 677 | 0 | P | S | F | 9 | 15 | 22 | 0.13 |

Thanks in advance for all the help!

So far all I've done is load the data:

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

df1 = pd.read_csv('LOGGED_DATA.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('PHOTOLOGGED_DATA.csv')
```

But I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to go about this.  I looked at inner, outer, etc joins.  But having the interval overlap, is throwing it off!

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframes you provided:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17'], 'From': [447.0, 472.0, 502.0, 503.8, 509.7, 527.0, 545.0, 551.0, 576.0, 579.5, 597.0, 616.0, 626.0, 647.0, 662.0], 'To': [472.0, 502.0, 503.8, 509.7, 527.0, 545.0, 551.0, 576.0, 579.5, 597.0, 616.0, 626.0, 647.0, 662.0, 677.0], 'Q': [0.63, 2.5, 2.5, 0.42, 0.38, 0.38, 3.33, 0.38, 6.07, 0.38, 0.38, 4.75, 0.38, 0.83, 0.38], 'RM': [42, 42, 37, 29, 32, 32, 47, 32, 47, 32, 32, 47, 32, 34, 37], 'RQ': [10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 26.67, 10.0, 48.57, 10.0, 10.0, 38.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17', 'MRC-17'], 'From': [499, 504, 510, 545, 565, 575, 581, 600, 612, 634, 647, 662], 'To': [504, 510, 545, 565, 575, 581, 600, 612, 634, 647, 662, 677], 'H': [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], 'DP': ['U', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P'], 'DR': ['S', 'R', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], 'IV': ['D', 'D', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'B', 'F'], 'No': [7, 7, 9, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 9, 7, 9], 'RQ': [50, 25, 5, 60, 5, 70, 20, 5, 70, 5, 55, 15], 'RM': [32, 32, 18, 28, 18, 34, 23, 18, 38, 22, 39, 22], 'Q': [2.08, 0.78, 0.02, 0.33, 0.02, 0.49, 0.11, 0.02, 2.92, 0.04, 4.58, 0.13]})
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Select non entirely overlapping rows from df1
mask = (df1["From"] >= df2["From"].min()) & (df1["From"] <= df2["From"].max()) | (
    df1["To"] >= df2["To"].min()
) & (df1["To"] <= df2["To"].max())
df1 = df1[~mask]

# Fix end value
df1.loc[df1.shape[0] - 1, "To"] = df2["From"].min()

# Make new dataframe from sliced df1 and df2, do some cleanup
new_df = (
    pd.concat([df1, df2])
    .fillna(value={"H": -99, "No": -99, "DP": "X", "DR": "X", "IV": "X"})
    .reindex(
        ["ID", "From", "To", "H", "DP", "DR", "IV", "No", "RQ", "RM", "Q"],
        axis="columns",
    )
    .astype(
        {"From": "int32", "To": "int32", "H": "int32", "No": "int32", "RQ": "int32"}
    )
)
```

And so:

```py
        ID  From   To   H DP DR IV  No  RQ  RM     Q
0   MRC-17   447  472 -99  X  X  X -99  10  42  0.63
1   MRC-17   472  499 -99  X  X  X -99  20  42  2.50
0   MRC-17   499  504   1  U  S  D   7  50  32  2.08
1   MRC-17   504  510   2  P  R  D   7  25  32  0.78
2   MRC-17   510  545   0  P  K  F   9   5  18  0.02
3   MRC-17   545  565   0  P  K  F   8  60  28  0.33
4   MRC-17   565  575   0  P  K  F   9   5  18  0.02
5   MRC-17   575  581   1  P  K  F   7  70  34  0.49
6   MRC-17   581  600   0  P  K  F   8  20  23  0.11
7   MRC-17   600  612   0  P  K  F   9   5  18  0.02
8   MRC-17   612  634   1  P  S  C   7  70  38  2.92
9   MRC-17   634  647   0  P  S  F   9   5  22  0.04
10  MRC-17   647  662   2  P  S  B   7  55  39  4.58
11  MRC-17   662  677   0  P  S  F   9  15  22  0.13
```